# How to extract info in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

i have to extract an info from a list with specific characters and spaces
this is my example :

```
[
    {
        LastUpdate            : 2022-02-14T15:27:30Z,
        DiagnosticMode        : LocalRequestFromLocalAPI,
        APIVersion            : 1.0.2,
        IPTV                  : 1,
        Telephony             : 0,
        DownstreamCurrRate    : 2488000,
        UpstreamCurrRate      : 1244000,
        DownstreamMaxBitRate  : 2488000,
        UpstreamMaxBitRate    : 1244000,
        Index                 : 2,
        Alternative           :
        [
            HGW
        ],
        Locations             : [],
        Groups                : [],
        SSW                   :
        {
            Capabilities : Master,
            CurrentMode  : Master
        },
        Names                 :
        [
            {
                Name   : LIVEBOX,
                Source : default,
                Suffix : ,
                Id     : default
            }
        ],
        DeviceTypes           :
        [
            {
                Source : default,
                Id     : default
            }
        ],
```

the info what i want is the APIVersion

Comment: You are expected to have made some effort to solve your problem before posting here.  Try writing this using https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.html (pay attention to subMatchVars) and post your code if you get stuck.

Comment: What data format is this?

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought this was a json file and it would be easily solved by using the json module in TclLib:
https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json.html

However, it's not valid json because none of the strings are in quotes. It also appears incomplete, you probably just cut and paste enough to get your point across.

Given that it's not valid json, then you could do a very general solution to open file, iterate the lines, then operate on the line matching `APIVersion`

```
set f [open file_that_looks_like_json.txt r]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach line $lines {
    if {[string match *APIVersion* $line]} {
        set version [string trimright [lindex $line 2] ","]
        puts $version
        break
    }
}
```